# Where was the DOS cdd utility from?

Tags: ms-dos, file-system, utilities

I distinctly remember, on the computer I had in the 90's, being able to type `cdd D:\bla\bla` in the MS-DOS command prompt, to change both the current directory *and* drive (avoiding having to type `D:` then `cd \bla\bla`).

I regularly still type it in the Windows command prompt, which complains that no such command exists. Then I remember I must do it with `cd /d D:\bla\bla`.

So it likely means this specific command wasn't actually part of MS-DOS. Did it come from some set of third-party utilities? I remember I might have something like Norton Utilities installed, but I couldn't find information about this specific tool in its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Utilities).

Or is my memory weak and I just made this up?

Comment: I wouldn't das you made it up, but maybe you made a batch to do so for you? As for myself I never ever heared of such a command.

Comment: By the way, generally I use `pushd` instead of `cd /d` - it is typed more easily (it's all letters, well distributed between the two hands, without need to shift to the symbols row) and you also get the bonus of `popd` to get back to where you were.

Comment: @Raffzahn it was actually very common and popular, back in the day

Comment: How badly do you want it to work on modern Windows?

Comment: Probably not what the asker was looking for, but FreeCOM offers `cdd`, `pushd` and `popd` as built-ins.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I remember `CDD` as a [4DOS](https://www.4dos.info/) command, which would have been available in the Norton Utilities as [NDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS#NDOS). JP Software’s other shells also implement `CDD`, so 4OS2 and 4NT users would probably recognise it too.

There are several external implementations of `CDD` too, both as batch files and binary executables. One was developed by Gary Mays in 1996, and provided as part of his “M” batch file enhancer (which I can’t find on the Internet right now). Several were published in PC Magazine, starting [in 1994](https://books.google.fr/books?id=E9TvMcu1mIwC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PA255), with revisions in [January 1995](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PRqVDFk1wcoC&lpg=PP1&vq=CDD.BAT&hl=fr&pg=PA239) and [December 1995](https://books.google.fr/books?id=zZluSj3AT6YC&lpg=PA266&vq=CDD.BAT&hl=fr&pg=PA265). Another was written by D. G. Sureau and released as freeware in 1993; it’s available [as part of Icon Shell](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/archive/ftp.sunet.se/pub/simtelnet/msdos/diskutil/is32.zip).

Under Windows you could use [Take Command](https://jpsoft.com/products/take-command.html) or [TCC](https://jpsoft.com/products/tcc-cmd-prompt.html), the descendants of 4DOS, which still include [CDD](https://jpsoft.com/help/cdd.htm), or write a command file to implement it.

Comment: Depending from what one was running in the 1990s, it could alternatively have been 4NT or 4OS2.  Also, present tense: Under Windows one _can_ use TCC.

Comment: @JdeBP I intended that as the conditional tense, not the past tense. (Note the present “still include CDD”.) The OP explicitly mentioned using DOS.

Comment: In Windows 7 and later, you can also create a CDD.BAT file that contains the single line `CD /D %1`. The only caveat is that you must `CALL CDD D:\FOO` if you want to use it within another batch file. TCC _would_ be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

cdd and cdd! were quite common DOS utilities.  eg search for cddbang or dos cdd

cd /d does not work under straight MS/PC-DOS.

Another frightfully useful utility is mcd, make and change directory.

```
c:>mcd c:\windows\system
c:\windows\system>
```

Would make the directory and change to it in a single line.

Comment: This may be true, but the question asks where did it come from.

Comment: cdd in its day was fairly popular even outside 4dos.  A lot of the features in 4dos exist in other command processors and in other programs.  cdd for example, was a pcmag utility,  I have five different dos versions, three of 'cdd.com' and two of 'cdd.exe'.

Answer (score -1):

*Disclaimer: I'm aware that this does **not** answer the question about a **tool of that name**. But chances are that no such tool was used...*

*EDIT: I overlooked the comment that confirmed the tool, sorry. Anyway, this might help when no tool is available.*

I am using "doskey" for this since at least since `cd` knows the option `/d`, and its macro:

```
cd=cd /d $*
```

This way there is no need to type `cdd`, just `cd`. You can change the name of the macro to your liking, of course.

*Final note: You could add an automatically run batch if you put its name in the registry at `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun`. Thats nice for some general stuff, like a better prompt.*

Comment: “But chances are that no such tool was used...” The OP confirmed that they used NDOS, so yes, such a tool was used.

Comment: What’s more, `CD /D` doesn’t work under plain DOS, so this couldn’t have worked. Or are you answering the part about doing this under Windows?